# Programmatically login a user like you can in ASP.net?

Tags: php, authentication

I've searched on this and I'm still not sure. In asp.net, I can programmatically login a user on the server side...and I'm not talking about a client-side script that fills in the forms automatically when they pull up the site. I can check something server-side and, if true, log them into the site. If false I can redirect to a user name/password form and make them type in the user name and password.

Is it possible to do something similar in PHP?

I have something I would like to do, but it sure would be nice not to waste time on something if it isn't even possible to begin with

Thanks!

-=-=-=

In asp.net the process works like this:

1. call uservalidate method to see if the credentials are correct
2. call formsauthentication.setauthcookie to set the authentication cookie
3. redirect user to predetermined page

e.g.,

```
    Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
    Response.Redirect("samepage.aspx");
```

Only on the redirect does the ticket get processed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Were this not possible, sites like Facebook would have to be pretty magical, eh? And most blog software. And most of the rest of the websites on the internet.

Comment: re: sites like Facebook would have to be pretty magical, eh? No, not really, you type in a user name and password at facebook. What I'm talking about, you don't. For instance, in asp.net, I could check to see if the user was from 12.192.191.15 and if True, log them in without the user typing in the user name and password and if false, send them to a login form. I don't know PHP very well, so that is what I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can - you need to read up on [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

1. You accept the user's credentials via a standard POST request sent from a form.
2. Take the credentials and check if they match (usually by querying a DB).
3. If they do, set a session variable to indicate the user has authenticated (`$_SESSION['user_is_authenticated'] = true`);
4. Check in your subsequent pages that needs to be secured if the user is authenticated or not - if he's not, redirect to login page: `if (!$_SESSION['user_is_authenticated']) header('location:login.php');`

Comment: Jahufar - accept credentials via a standard POST request sent from a form. That is the part I can skip in asp.net that I wasn't sure about in PHP. For example, in asp.net, I wrote a program to get a hardware serial no. and send it to the server in an encrypted cookie. If the serial validates, I log them in without the user doing anything.  I was kind of thinking about a PHP plugin that would let my program work with PHP (via a shared database between asp.net and PHP). Logging them in if "True" without ANY user credentials is the issue. But it looks possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ASP, but you'd simply just set the session in PHP. For example, if your login scripts looks for a user object in the session, you'd just load that user from your datasource and load it into the session. You'd also need to set whatever other flags you might be checking.

This is a common requirement when you want to give admins the ability to login as a user in your site.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I have used it a tiny bit. I think it may work. What I want to do is check a shared database between an asp.net app and a PHP site. If a bit in the database is "true," they can get logged in the PHP site without the user name and password field. If they fail to validate, it kicks them to a forms-based login. This was pretty easy in asp.net. I just didn't know if it would be possible in PHP. Thanks